after http->https Migration, jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function
It worked well before, but after migrating from HTTP to HTTPS, modal pop-ups are not working.
The browser's warning message warns as follows.

jQuery version is 3.5.1.
Alert Messege : jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function.

problematic part :
jQuery(".pop_album").fancybox

fancybox code :
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/11.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
    jQuery(".pop_album").fancybox ({
        padding     : 0,
        margin      : 20,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : 600,
        height      : 600,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type        : 'iframe',
        helpers:  {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        },
         beforeShow: function () {
           var newWidth = 600; // set new image display width
           $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('img').css({
               width  : newWidth,
               height : "auto"
           }); // apply new size to img
       }

    });
</script> 


In your given code fancybox jquery library is not added.That is the reason
